# Resolving php command line errors

Tags: php

When I run php -v from the command line, I get a number of warnings before it finally tells me the version I'm running. I don't know where to begin to resolve them.

Here are the errors. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/msql.so' - dlopen(/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/msql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/msql.so' - dlopen(/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/msql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/open_ssl.so' - dlopen(/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/open_ssl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/open_ssl.so' - dlopen(/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/open_ssl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'xsl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.17 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2012 14:16:56) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

(I'm wondering if there is a conflict between the php installation that came with my Mac (OS 10.7.5) and the php version I installed using MacPorts (which is configured to my Apache Installation -- also installed with MacPorts). I want to get this resolved so I can use php dependency manager composer without any issues. I can't be sure if a conflict is responsible for the errors: the version (5.3.17) and build date output by the command line is the same as the version and build date out by localhost using `phpinfo()`.)

Comment: Find out which configuration files are being used, edit them to remove broken/duplicate references to extensions (`extension = curl.so` or similar).

Comment: So you're exactly right - I had made manually tried to enable these customizations in my php.ini file: extension=msql.so
extension=xsl.so
extension=curl.so
extension=open_ssl.so. I commented them out, and I no longer get the errors. My only other question is why is everything still working? I restarted apache and php and everything works great. But where are these extensions getting enabled? They don't seem present anywhere else in the init file. Are they enable by default? The errors say already loaded in "unknown" on line 0. What does that mean?

Comment: Your main file will be loading a directory